# Overriding the client-side error message in the jQuery function so value can be added

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations, client-side

I'd like to start by saying that this site has been incredibly helpful in getting up to speed with MVC and DataAnnotations. Now, onto the question.

First, some facts: I'm using MVC2 and the .NET 4.0 framework. Updating to MVC3 is not currently an option for me (which is the most common answer to half the problems I've encountered, but it might not actually matter here).

I've created a fully working custom attribute to verify if a string already exists in a database result set. I've also created the matching custom validator and javascript to output client-side metadata, and it too also works.

What I'd like to solve is how to override the error message that the client is using through jquery/javascript, **not** through my validator. I want the client-side error message to include the value of the input field when it is invalid, which is impossible to do through the validator. So, some code:

Validator:

```
public class UniqueStringValidator : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<UniqueStringAttribute>
    {
        public UniqueStringValidator(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext controllerContext,
                                    UniqueStringAttribute attribute)
            : base(metadata, controllerContext, attribute)
        {

        }

        public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
        {
            //declare the services we'll need

            var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
            {
                ValidationType = "uniquestring",
                ErrorMessage = "The string is not unique.", //I want to override this on the client, but NOT HERE
            };

            //This is how I pull additional attributes from the viewmodel in MVC2 (wish I was on MVC3)
            //"c" represents the current record we're editing, if we're editing
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["c"] != null)
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request["c"]);
                string[] stringNames = //call a service and add some query to remove the current record from the results
                    //and return only the column of strings we're interested in

                rule.ValidationParameters.Add("stringlist", stringNames);
            }
            else
            //If we're here, we're not editing an existing record
            {
                string[] stringNames = //call a service and query only the column of interest
                rule.ValidationParameters.Add("stringlist", stringNames);
            }

            return new[] { rule };
        }
    }
```

Here's my javascript validator:

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("uniquestring", function (value, element, params) {

    var stringNames = params.stringlist;

    for (var i = 0; i < stringNames .length; i++) {
        if (value == stringNames [i]) {
            //I want to override the error message here so I can include value
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
});
```

I've revisited this a bit and tried a few more things to really understand what's going on. The error message is set in the metadata at the bottom of the page, and all the javascript function seems capable of doing is determining if the validation should pass or fail. Adding an error message at the end of the function with jquery, or even attempting to set the error message element to some text in the javascript does not seem to make a difference or breaks the script (I suspect the later approach "works" but is immediately overwritten by the metadata).

Any suggestions?

Comment: No thoughts yet? I still haven't found out how to access the error message in the javascript validator so I'm still looking for options.

Comment: After the `function` argument to `addMethod`, try supplying a string to use as the error message. That *should* override the default error message.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for your response. Unfortunately, there does not appear to be any obvious place to arbitrarily add a string to the definition of the function or script in general. I've tried it after the closing parenthesis of the function, the closing curly brace of the function, and after the params parameter. In all cases, it appears to be either ignored or outright breaks the script.

Comment: `$.validator.addMethod("uniquestring", function (value, element, params) { ... }, "My error message");`. MVC might be doing funky like overriding the error message but I figured it was worth a shot.

Comment: That's something I did not try until your initial suggestion, but a string at that position appears to be ignored.

Comment: I believe @Rich_Wagenknecht answered your question below.  You do not have to override all error messages; you can select which error messages to override based on the id of the input, if that is part of your logic.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Microsoft's unobtrusive validation, the error message is indeed set for you and will override the message you're trying to provide in your validator. The message you provide in your validator (through addMethod) is the default message if none is specified in the options when the jquery validator is created.

For unobtrusive validation, the error message is included as an attribute on the element being validated (I don't have MVC2, but this is true for 3 and 4)

You can, however, still override this message manually.

Assuming your form looked like this:

```
<form action="/controller/action" id="myForm" method="post">        
<input data-val="true" data-val-uniquestring="The string is not unique" type="text" name="foo" id="foo"/>
    <div data-valmsg-for="foo"></div>
    <button type="submit">Ok</button>
</form>
```

You can see the error message is specified in the attribute of the element which will override the default error message you provided when you setup the validator.

To change all instances of this message you could do something like this:

```
function myCustomMessage(ruleParams, element) {
    return $(element).val() + " is not a unique value";
}

// This snippet must come after the jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js file
$(function () {
    var settings = $("#myForm").validate().settings;

    for (var p in settings.messages) {
        if (typeof settings.messages[p]["uniquestring"] !== "undefined") {
            settings.messages[p]["uniquestring"] = myCustomMessage;
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: In my case, the error message is actually contained in the metadata at the bottom of the page, as opposed to being inside a html element, prior to triggering on an error. There can be multiple possible error messages (and combinations of messages) for a single input field, so changing the entire error message wholesale is also not an option.

Comment: Excellent, I've searched far and wide for this solution, thank you so much. In my case I want to insert values into the message, and since I know it is there and what it will be named I can reference it like so without the need to loop through the entire collection:  settings.messages.Id_Of_Input.validationtype = 'my custom message', . where "validationtype" is the value returned by the ModelClientValidationRule.ValidationType.